# Why are the values ​of the expression not displayed in numeric format?

Tags: octave

I have an expression (signal) and I want to get certain results using a loop.
Original formula
[image]

Code:

```
Ak=1.2;
fk=0.0123;
jK=0.321;
alphaK=-0.01;
T=1;

#Signal
#xi=1.2*cos(0,0123*2*pi*(i-1)+0.321)*eps(–0.01*i);

for i=1:4
  x(i)=Ak*cos(fk*2*pi*(i-1)+jK)*eps(alphaK*i);
end
```

The results are in this format

```
x = 1.9753e-18
x = 1.9753e-18   3.8375e-18
x = 1.9753e-18   3.8375e-18   3.7013e-18
x = 1.9753e-18   3.8375e-18   3.7013e-18   7.0863e-18
```

But the correct results look like this:

[image]

How do I change the format to get the correct display?

Comment: It's not a formatting issue. The results are different.

Comment: are you sure about using `eps` ?  https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Mathematical-Constants.html#index-eps

Comment: @matzeri 
I added a formula in the main message of the topic, which I encoded in an octave. And there is e.

Comment: May be you are looking for exp instead of eps ?

Comment: Side note. There is no need of a loop in this case in Octave. You should use matricial operations as much as possible in Octave/MATLAB. Replace the loop with: `i=1:4; x=Ak*cos(fk*2*pi*(i-1)+jK).*exp(alphaK*i);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
x(i)=Ak*cos(fk*2*pi*(i-1)+jK)*eps(alphaK*i);
```

with

```
x(i)=Ak*cos(fk*2*pi*(i-1)+jK)*exp(alphaK*i);
```

and you will have a result much near to the expected one

```
x =

   1.12737   1.08417   1.03531   0.98119
```

eps is NOT the exponential function

```
octave:3> eps
ans =    2.2204e-16
octave:4> eps(x)
ans =

   2.2204e-16   2.2204e-16   2.2204e-16   1.1102e-16
octave:5> exp(x)
ans =

   3.0875   2.9570   2.8160   2.6676
```

Comment: may be worth including that `eps` refers to [`machine precision`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/eps.html).

Comment: Sure, but RTFM (Read the fine manual) should be a given in this context. Or of course I assume, but I am also old...